# Removing parts of url using php print

Tags: php

I want to retireve page url using php but I would like some parts removed

```
<?php print("http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>


Example: http://url.com/questions/page/112/
Result: http://url.com/page/112/
```

I would like to remove `questions/` within the url. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url="http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$url=str_replace('/questions','',$url);
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use mod_rewrite, a module available in apache. This will be managed by an .htaccess file within your web directory. AddedBytes has a nice tutorial for beginners on url-rewriting.

[check this site for detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606191430/http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use php's explode function to split the example up into an array separated by "/"s, then loop through the array and where the array value = questions, unset or remove it from the array.

// Example 1

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Here's an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove it as a string, you can use

```
$url = str_replace('/questions', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

If you then want to redirect user to that page, you need to send a header (before any output):

```
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $url);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$str = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$parts = explode("/",$str);

$tmp = array();
for($i = 0; $i<count($parts)-2;$i++){
   $tmp[$i] = $parts[$i];
}

$output = implode("/",$tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$sentence = str_replace('questions/', '', 'http://url.com/questions/page/112/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This splits the uri into an array
$uri = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

//Then Remove the first part of the uri (ie questions)
$first_uri = array_shift($uri);

//Recreate the string from the array
$uri = implode("/", $uri);

//Print like in your example
print("http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $uri);

//You can also access the remove string (questions) in the $first_uri variable
print($first_uri); //returns questions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].preg_replace('/^\/questions/i','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $url;
```